# Date and Time string parse

Tags: python

I have a date time string formatted as follows:

**2012-12-03T02:00:00Z**

I want to split the date and time up and display it as follows:
03/12/2012 02:00:00

How can I do this in python in as few a lines as possible?? (The 'T' and 'Z' will be removed)

Answer (score 2):

This goes through the `datetime` library and will throw an exception if the input string is not correctly formatted or contains an invalid datetime information (leap years included!).

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2012-12-03T02:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```